# Maintaining similar Android projects

Tags: java, android, git, maven

We currently have an application which is essentially a fully-functional demo for potential clients.  All the functionality is there.  However, we use generic branding/logos, call our own web services (which would later be swapped out for calls to client web-services), etc.

Here is my question.  If we have two different clients, we would prefer as little duplicate code as possible.  I understand that this could be done -- from a java perspective -- by simply including a shared JAR.  However, we will need to change around resources.  Also, one client may not want some functionality that another client does want.  On top of this, if we are doing general bug fixes, we will normally want these fixes to be in both versions  of the application.

We are using Git for version control and Maven for building the project.

One option we discussed is simply branching the project and maintaining separate versions.  However, then we would have to manually merge changes that we want reflected in all versions of the app.

Another option we discussed is somehow swapping out resources, etc. using maven profiles.  However, if we need to make any non-superficial changes to the code itself, this could be a problem.  We might have to get into factories and different implementations.

Does anyone have recommendations on the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

We use a library project with git submodules to handle all of our similar projects. The master project is pretty hefty but we use a configuration file to determine what features should be in the finished product.